# Reprojection of satellite images mosaic to CRS with latitude and longitudes

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geopandas, rasterio, extract-by-mask

I downloaded MODIS product MOD13A1 for India. Then mosaiced the granules in GeoTIFF format using rasterio Python library. I have the appropriate shapefile to mask the mosaiced raster.

After mosaicing granules:

[image: Mosaiced Raster]

```
mosaic shape: (1, 12001, 14401)

crs: CRS({'proj': 'utm', 'zone': 35, 'ellps': 'GRS80', 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True}) (found using mosaic.crs of rasterio library)
```

meta of mosaic file:

[image]

Shapefile I am using (converted to png to upload here):

[image]

CRS of shapefile: [epsg:4326]

I want to mask the mosaic using shapefile above.
To bring them in same CRS I converted mosaic to EPSG:4326

Code to reproject mosaic:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'

with rasterio.open('mark_2.tif') as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

with rasterio.open('reproject_mark_2.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
    for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
        reproject(
            source=rasterio.band(src, i),
            destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
            src_transform=src.transform,
            src_crs=src.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Code to mask mosaic using shapefile:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

with fiona.open("india_shape_file/IND_adm0.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open('mosaic.tif') as src:
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features,
                                                    crop=True)
out_meta = src.meta.copy()
```

But something is going wrong.

Reprojected mosaic:

[image]

Meta of reprojected file:

[image]

After masking:

[image]

Mosaicing Code:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.plot import show
import glob
import os

dirpath = '37758/*'
search_criteria = 'MOD13A1_A2010001*.tif'
q = os.path.join(dirpath, search_criteria)

files = glob.glob(q)

mosaic_files = []

for fp in files:
    src = rasterio.open(fp)
    mosaic_files.append(src)

mosaic, out_trans = merge(mosaic_files)
out_meta = src.meta.copy()
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                 "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_trans,
                 "crs": "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
"})

with rasterio.open('mark_2.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(mosaic)
```

Reprojection is wrong. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ? I have tried the same in QGIS but result is same. Finally, I have to do this programmatically.

Comment: I doubt that your mosaic is really in UTM 35N, which is not a suitable CRS for India anyway. Could it be sinusoidal instead?

Comment: Individual granules were sinusoidal projection but after mosaicing it shows UTM. Here is the meta of single granule:                                                     {'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'int16',
 'nodata': None,
 'width': 2400,
 'height': 2400,
 'count': 1,
 'crs': CRS({'proj': 'sinu', 'lon_0': 0, 'x_0': 0, 'y_0': 0, 'a': 6371007.181, 'b': 6371007.181, 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True}),
 'transform': Affine(463.31271652750013, 0.0, 4447802.078667,
        0.0, -463.31271652750013, 4447802.078667)}

Comment: The corner coordinates of the affine transformation let me think that the mosaicing result is still in the same sinusoidal projection. The images are still 2400px squares. They would be distorted in any UTM projection.

Comment: @AndreJ I don't understand. If it is still in sinusoidal projection why is it showing otherwise. Also, after mosaicing why would image be 2400 px (or are you referring to granules ?). Could you please explain what is going wrong and what can be done ?

Comment: The single modis images are 2400px squares. You merged 6x5 images, and got a 14400x12000 image, without any reprojection. Maybe you should add the mosaicking commands you used.

Comment: @AndreJ I have added the mosaicing code. Thank you for such timely reply.

Comment: So you just wrote the `UTM 35` in the metadata, but that did not reproject the raster to that. You better insert the sinu projection there.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. Still masked image is a little shifted . I don't know if that is normal. But it serves my purpose nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

In mosaicing code snippet out_meta has been updated manually.

```
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
             "height": mosaic.shape[1],
             "width": mosaic.shape[2],
             "transform": out_trans,
             "crs": "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
"})
```

"crs": "+proj=utm" is setting the projection of mosaiced file to UTM when it should be sinusoidal.

Correct code will be:

```
"crs": "+proj=sinu +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Comment: `+zone=35` does not make sense for a sinusoidal projection. You should replace the ellipsoid with the a and b parameters you reported from a single MODIS image in your comment above. Or try to take the whole crs information from it.